# How can I get the last row without order by and assign a value to a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that is within a View so I can not use order by . I have a column called **Course** that column is an Int Column and it can have many repeating values . There is also a column called **status** that status column is also an Int and it will have unique values . I am trying to create a query where we can get the last row of a particular **Course** and see if the Status is 2 if yes then add 1 to @MyValue if not then add 0 to the variable .I have an **ID** column which is the primary key, without order by I am having a tough time figuring this one out .

- MyValue is a **smallint** and we simply assign the value
- CourseNumber is a **Int** and a table can have many (Course) @CourseNumber with the same number
- **There will only be 1** combination of CourseNumber and Status . We can have many CourseNumbers with the same number etc 120 however each one will have a different **Status**

What I want to do with the query below is get the last record of @CourseNumber we have an ID column and check if the status of the last record of @CourseNumber is equal to 2 . If it's equal to 2 then assign the value 1 to @MyValue and if it is not equal to 2 then assign the value 0 .

```
    SELECT @MyValue =(SELECT count(*) FROM MyTasks as MT WHERE MT.Course = @CourseNumber And MT.status=2)
```

Sample: ID Course Status

1. 1   23  4
2. 2   23  5
3. 3   23  2
4. 4   23  1

Assuming that was the database table the Course is [@CourseNumber] is 23 . We would want to get the last row of the Course number which is [4] and we would want the status which is [1] since the status is not 2 for that last row we would just return a 0 and we would only return a 1 if the last row of the course number has a status of 1 .  This is a sql function inside of a view . I try to leave out some of things that might not be necessary since it is a large View and function .

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What does it mean to "have a query that is within a view"?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. You say you're inside a `VIEW` so can't use `ORDER BY` (which isn't completely true, subqueries inside said view *can* use `ORDER BY` for example) but then say you want to assign a value to variable; variables can't be used inside a `VIEW` so your point about the `VIEW` becomes moot. Something like `SET @MyVariable = (SELECT TOP (1) MyColumn FROM MyView ORDER BY SomeColumn DESC)` is perfectly valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to self join to the table to determine the maximum ID value to find the record you want.  You say add 1 to @MyValue and later you say to set @MyValue = 1.  This will add 1 to @MyValue.  If you want @MyValue = 1, change the case statement removing the @MyValue parameter.

```
DECLARE @MyValue INT = 0
    , @CourseNumber INT = 23

SELECT @MyValue = CASE WHEN t0.Status = 2 THEN @MyValue + 1 ELSE @MyValue END
FROM MyTasks t0 
JOIN 
( 
    SELECT Couse
        , MAX(ID) MAXID 
    FROM MyTasks 
    WHERE Course = @CourseNumber 
) t1 ON t0.Course = t1.Course AND t0.ID = t1.MAXID
```